# Sorting multiple COUNT instances in mysql?

Tags: mysql, count

```
SELECT
smart_curmonth_portals.portal_name,
COUNT(smart_curmonth_portals.portal_name) as Hits,
COUNT(smart_curmonth_portals.page_name is 'Home') as Home*******
COUNT(smart_curmonth_portals.page_name is not 'Home') as Subpage*******
COUNT(smart_curmonth_portals.page_name is NULL) as Downloads*******
FROM
smart_curmonth_portals
GROUP BY
smart_curmonth_portals.portal_name
ORDER BY
Hits DESC
```

I have a table - smart_curmonth_portals that I use to do reporting on user hits.  I don't do the analysis reports - and its not formatted well so I can't change that.  The table has the following:

1. portal_name - currently doing COUNT on this and works
2. page_name - gives the exact page a person went to when they went to portal in #1.  Most of the time it is 'Home', sometimes it is a subpage which would have a random name, and sometimes it is NULL and goes to #3.
3. doctitle - The NULLs on #2 are just direct item downloads and each of these have name - which we don't need but we need a count.

Would like to see:

```
Portal_Name   Hits   Home   Subpages    Downloads
Testportal    3000   2300    600        100
```

Comment: that query's outright invalid. `is` cannot be used for equality tests like that.

Comment: @MarcB - I understand that but I am trying to figure out if it can be done without multiple SELECTs.

Comment: `select sum(page_name = 'HOME')` type stuff would work. mysql will convert the boolean true/false of the equality test to integer 0 or 1 and then sum up the 1's.

Answer (score 2):

`COUNT(x)` counts the number of times that `x` is not null.  In your query, it is probably returning the total number of rows (or close to it) for all the values.

If you want the number of rows where the conditions are true, then use `sum()`:

```
SELECT scp.portal_name,
       sum(scp.portal_name) as Hits,
       sum(scp.page_name = 'Home') as Home,
       sum(scp.page_name <> 'Home') as Subpage,
       sum(scp.page_name is NULL) as Downloads
FROM smart_curmonth_portals scp
GROUP BY scp.portal_name
ORDER BY Hits DESC ;
```

Comment: when Gordon is here, it must be right his answer :) . we should answer somewhere else :) .

Comment: Gordon is an IBM computer.  He has an answer to everything before I hit submit.  2 issues - I had to change the sum on the "Hits" line to COUNT or everything was jacked up.  Also I have a question about the <> Home - does that include NULL?  If so how do I take NULL out?  And thank you so I don't keep having to make these huge view queries with tons of different SELECTs.

Comment: @blankip . . . Both `page_name = 'Home'` and `page_name <> 'Home'` ignore `NULL` values.  All comparisons other than explicit `NULL` comparisons fail when either value (or both) is null.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation - I thought so and looking at the #s it looked good but good to hear this from the informed - sure it will help others.

Answer (score 1):

A general (not specific to MySQL) solution would be:

```
select portal_name
    ,COUNT(portal_name) as Hits
    ,COUNT(case when page_name = 'Home' then 1 end) as Home
    ,COUNT(case when page_name <> 'Home' then 1 end) as Subpage
    ,COUNT(case when page_name is null then 1 end) as Downloads
from smart_curmonth_portals
group by portal_name
order by Hits desc
```

Comment: This works too.  What is the difference between your statement and Gordon's performance-wise?  I need to start using CASE more in my scripting.  My stuff is a big gob of nested SELECTs.